# Wrong ByteArray Returned From SequenceFileRecordReader

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs, user-defined-functions

I am trying to read binary network packet data stored in a HDFS SequenceFile. Problem seems to be with the non-printable characters, or in the packet header.

Currently the data is stored into HDFS with Flume-ng (1.4), through a custom plugin (jpcap with global tcpdump header stripped). Events are submitted on a per-packet basis. This is further the way I read it back into Pig, with a SequenceFile RecordReader.

Per now, to keep it simple, I don't do anything else than reading the records from the seq-file and writing it straight to file (output.pcap).

input.pcap excerpt (retrieved from HDFS):

```
00000ab0  00 00 08 00 00 01 42 5c  4a e1 e9 00 00 00 00 00  |......B\J.......|
00000ac0  00 01 cf 00 00 00 08 00  00 01 42 5c 4a e1 ea 00  |..........B\J...|
00000ad0  00 01 c3 47 45 54 20 2f  20 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e  |...GET / HTTP/1.|
00000ae0  31 0d 0a 48 6f 73 74 3a  20 31 39 32 2e 31 36 38  |1..Host: 192.168|
00000af0  2e 31 30 39 2e 31 32 38  0d 0a 41 63 63 65 70 74  |.109.128..Accept|
```

output.pcap same bulk excerpt (from Pig UDF):

```
000009a0  fa 83 31 5d 7d da 1e a0  b7 32 4f 50 65 ab 61 28  |..1]}....2OPe.a(|
000009b0  b1 ee 2b 6d 22 74 d9 64  bf 8d 60 23 62 a9 c5 ac  |..+m"t.d..`#b...|
000009c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000a40  00 00 01 c3 47 45 54 20  2f 20 48 54 54 50 2f 31  |....GET / HTTP/1|
00000a50  2e 31 0d 0a 48 6f 73 74  3a 20 31 39 32 2e 31 36  |.1..Host: 192.16|
00000a60  38 2e 31 30 39 2e 31 32  38 0d 0a 41 63 63 65 70  |8.109.128..Accep|
```

As you may see the first hex dump shows 0x01425c4ae2ee, which translates to a timestamp: 1384527880942, or Fri, 15 Nov 2013 15:04:40 GMT. The other one just shows nills until the start of the packet data.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction here, so that I can read out the packet header consisting of e.g.:

```
c2 ba cd 4f b6 35 0f 00  36 00 00 00 36 00 00 00

1-4b:   Timestamp, 0x4fcdbac2. 
calc 0x4fcdbac2 -> 1338882754
-> date --date='1970-01-01 1338882754 sec GMT’

5-8b:   Microseconds of timestamp

9-12b:  Packet data size

13-16b: Length of packet as it was captured on the wire (54b). Can be the same as 9-12b but can be different if snapshot length (max packet 
    length) is less than 65536
```

Without any more introduction, here goes PcapFileLoader.java:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.BooleanWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.ByteWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.FloatWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.SerializationFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileRecordReader;
import org.apache.pig.FileInputLoadFunc;
import org.apache.pig.LoadFunc;
import org.apache.pig.backend.BackendException;
import org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigSplit;
import org.apache.pig.data.DataByteArray;
import org.apache.pig.data.DataType;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.data.TupleFactory;
import org.krakenapps.pcap.util.ByteOrderConverter;

public class PcapFileLoader extends FileInputLoadFunc {

    private SequenceFileRecordReader<LongWritable, BytesWritable> reader;

    private Writable key;
    private BytesWritable value;

    private ArrayList<Object> mProtoTuple = null;

    protected TupleFactory mTupleFactory = TupleFactory.getInstance();
    protected SerializationFactory serializationFactory;

    protected byte[] currentPacket;

    protected byte keyType = DataType.UNKNOWN;
    protected byte valType = DataType.UNKNOWN;

    public PcapFileLoader() {
        mProtoTuple = new ArrayList<Object>(2);
    }

    protected void setKeyType(Class<?> keyClass) throws BackendException {
        this.keyType |= inferPigDataType(keyClass);
        if (keyType == DataType.ERROR) {
            throw new BackendException("Unable to translate " + key.getClass() + " to a Pig datatype");
        }
    }

    protected void setValueType(Class<?> valueClass) throws BackendException {
        this.valType |= inferPigDataType(valueClass);
        if (keyType == DataType.ERROR) {
            throw new BackendException("Unable to translate " + key.getClass() + " to a Pig datatype");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Tuple getNext() throws IOException {
        boolean next = false;
        try {
            next = reader.nextKeyValue();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }

        if (!next) {
            return null;
        }

        key = reader.getCurrentKey();
        value = reader.getCurrentValue();

        currentPacket = value.getBytes();
        if (keyType == DataType.UNKNOWN && key != null) {
            setKeyType(key.getClass());
        }
        if (valType == DataType.UNKNOWN && value != null) {
            setValueType(value.getClass());
        }

        //readPacketHeader();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(currentPacket);
        long ts = buffer.getLong();
        ts = ByteOrderConverter.swap(ts);
        System.out.println(ts);

        FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("output.pcap"),true);
        file.write(value.getBytes());
        file.close();

        mProtoTuple.add(translateWritableToPigDataType(key, keyType));
        mProtoTuple.add(translateWritableToPigDataType(value, valType));
        Tuple t = mTupleFactory.newTuple(mProtoTuple);
        mProtoTuple.clear();
        return t;
    }

    protected byte inferPigDataType(Type t) {
        if (t == DataByteArray.class) {
            return DataType.BYTEARRAY;
        } else if (t == BytesWritable.class) {
            return DataType.BYTEARRAY;
        } else if (t == Text.class) {
            return DataType.CHARARRAY;
        } else if (t == IntWritable.class) {
            return DataType.INTEGER;
        } else if (t == LongWritable.class) {
            return DataType.LONG;
        } else if (t == FloatWritable.class) {
            return DataType.FLOAT;
        } else if (t == DoubleWritable.class) {
            return DataType.DOUBLE;
        } else if (t == BooleanWritable.class) {
            return DataType.BOOLEAN;
        } else if (t == ByteWritable.class) {
            return DataType.BYTE;
        } // not doing maps or other complex types for now
        else {
            return DataType.ERROR;
        }
    }

    protected Object translateWritableToPigDataType(Writable w, byte dataType) {
        switch (dataType) {
            case DataType.CHARARRAY:
                return ((Text) w).toString();
            case DataType.BYTEARRAY:
                return (w instanceof BytesWritable ? new DataByteArray(((BytesWritable) w).getBytes()) : w);
            case DataType.BOOLEAN:
                return ((BooleanWritable) w).get();
            case DataType.INTEGER:
                return ((IntWritable) w).get();
            case DataType.LONG:
                return ((LongWritable) w).get();
            case DataType.FLOAT:
                return ((FloatWritable) w).get();
            case DataType.DOUBLE:
                return ((DoubleWritable) w).get();
            case DataType.BYTE:
                return ((ByteWritable) w).get();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public InputFormat getInputFormat() throws IOException {
        return new SequenceFileInputFormat<LongWritable, BytesWritable>();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void prepareToRead(RecordReader reader, PigSplit split)
            throws IOException {
        this.reader = (SequenceFileRecordReader) reader;
    }

    @Override
    public void setLocation(String location, Job job) throws IOException {
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, location);
    }
}
```

Can e.g. be invoked through a pig script:

```
%DEFAULT includepath includes.pig
RUN $includepath;

seq = LOAD 'good.newest.pcap' using PcapFileLoader() as (a: long, b: bytearray);

DUMP seq;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem in this case was understanding the dataset. Normally one would (those solutions I've seen anyway) start analysing the IP layer, while JPCAP provides the Ethernet header as well. Because of that the IP layer is number two in the chain. At the end I found some good docs hidden [here](https://github.com/jpcap/jpcap/tree/master/docs/ethernet/ip) as well.